# Storing channels' data in Go

Tags: go

Can we store and retrieve data from a channel?

For instance, can I store c, in the code below, somewhere?

```
package main

    import (
        "fmt"
    )

    func main() {

        c := make(chan int)

        go func(){

            c <- 42
        }()
        fmt.Println(<-c)
    }
```

Comment: `other := <-c` will store the value(42) in `other` once the channel is populated.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it "does not show any research effort" and "it is unclear". Be sure to take the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it anywhere you like but channels are only a method for passing information within a Go program. Where the data comes from and what you do with it is entirely up to you.

I strongly recommend going through the Go tour, and specifically [here](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/2) for channels.